# How to simulate our own ssh binary in Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have a command such as

```
ssh -S myAuthServer hostname
```

Was trying to create a code snippet and I'm not sure how to implement the `-S` part
The code I have at the moment:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import paramiko
from paramiko import SSHClient, SSHConfig, SSHException

paramiko.util.log_to_file("/tmp/script.log")

def getSSHConnection():
    config = SSHConfig()


    host='server1'        

    # setup SSH client
    client = SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    #Check for proxy settings
    proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand('ssh -S myAuthServer root@%s' % host)
    print "proxy:", proxy

    #Setup the SSH connection
    try:
        if (proxy is None):
            client.connect(host, port=22, username='root')
        else:
            print "-> Using paramiko with proxy"
            client.connect(host, port=22, username='root', sock=proxy)

    except SSHException, ex:
        print ex

    if client:
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('hostname')
        tables=stdout.readlines()

        print "stdin:", stdin
        print "stdout:", stdout
        print "stderr:", stderr
        print "tables:", tables    

    return client

getSSHConnection()
```

The error I'm receiving is

```
INF [20181011-11:14:55.131] thr=1   paramiko.hostkeys: Unable to handle key of type 1024
DEB [20181011-11:14:55.161] thr=2   paramiko.transport: starting thread (client mode): 0x4f35fd0L
DEB [20181011-11:14:55.161] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.2.1
ERR [20181011-11:15:10.242] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner
ERR [20181011-11:15:10.245] thr=2   paramiko.transport: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERR [20181011-11:15:10.246] thr=2   paramiko.transport:   File "/Users/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1805, in run
ERR [20181011-11:15:10.246] thr=2   paramiko.transport:     self._check_banner()
ERR [20181011-11:15:10.246] thr=2   paramiko.transport:   File "/Users/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1957, in _check_banner
ERR [20181011-11:15:10.246] thr=2   paramiko.transport:     'Error reading SSH protocol banner' + str(e)
ERR [20181011-11:15:10.246] thr=2   paramiko.transport: SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
ERR [20181011-11:15:10.246] thr=2   paramiko.transport:
```

Comment: I smell [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578) here - Consider explaining us, what you are trying to implement functional-wise.

Comment: I need to authenticate my connection against some proxy as another level of security, otherwise, no matter how much my personal keys match - I won't be able to connect due to the middle man. from @martins' answer - I understood that my approach to solve this is all wrong ...

Comment: And that's it. I do not see what `-S` has to do with proxying a connection. So do I understand right, that even your choice of `-S` was unsubstantiated?

Comment: yes, from your answer I got the point that i was confused between `scp`'s `-S` and assumed it exists in `ssh` .... because when we need `scp` we do `-S oursshbinary`, and when I just need to ssh somewhere I just run `oursshbinary $server ls -al` - but I don't understand how can I do that with `Paramiko`. ( `oursshbinary` replaces our native linux `ssh` command that already implements our proxy/auth behavior )

Comment: You cannot make Paramiko use `oursshbinary`. You cannot even make it use `ssh`. Paramiko **is `ssh` itself**. It's same (as you know now), as if you wanted `ssh` use `oursshbinary` (it makes no sense). You would have to make Paramiko do what `oursshbinary` does. But we do not know what `oursshbinary` does, comparing to `ssh`. That's for a new question, now that you know what to ask.

Comment: Though as you planned to use `oursshbinary` anyway from your Python code, you actually can run `oursshbinary` directly from Python, without any Paramiko at all.

Comment: So, as I've commented initially, this is XY problem.

Comment: `you actually can run oursshbinary directly from Python, without any Paramiko at al` - that's what we do now ... but we wanted the ease of using Paramiko's features vs `subprocess` ... :/ ...

Many thanks for your answers - it's all clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make Paramiko use `oursshbinary` as an SSH implementation. You cannot even make it use `ssh`.

**Paramiko is `ssh` itself.**

It's same (as you know now), as if you wanted `ssh` use `oursshbinary` (it makes no sense). You would have to make Paramiko do what `oursshbinary` does. But we do not know what `oursshbinary` does, comparing to `ssh`.

---

Response to the previous version of your question:

The `-S` switch of OpenSSH `ssh` client creates a connection sharing that can be reused by other instances of `ssh` or other OpenSSH tools (like `sftp`).

Paramiko does not support connection sharing. It makes no sense for it to do actually.

Connection sharing makes sense for tools/applications. One instance of a tool creates a connection and other instances of the same or different tool can reuse the connection.

But you do not need that in a script/when programming. You have your SSH session instance. You can use it for multiple purposes throughout your script/program. In other words, you can *share* your instance.

Specifically, with SSH, the OpenSSH connection sharing opens separate SSH channel for the sharing client. With Paramiko, you can open multiple separated channels over the same SSH connection as well. This is what methods like `Transport.open_sftp_client` (or `SSHClient.open_sftp`), `Transport.open_session` (`SSHClient.invoke_shell`, `SSHClient.exec_command`) do. They all internally call `Transport.open_channel`. You can call all these as many times as you need, for a single SSH session.